# Is Asp.Net Core Identity suitable for Grpc service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, grpc-c#

We need to build a *Grpc service*, which must feature users, external login, sign-in/sign-out, roles, etc. We plan to use *EF Core* for our database, so we consider using *ASP.NET Core Identity* for all that "user stuff".

Will *Grpc* work nicely with *ASP.NET Core Identity*? I just found out that Microsoft suggests **not to use** their *Identity* framework for web APIs (mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity). So did I misunderstand them, or are there pitfalls in that approach?

Comment: could you specify what part of the doc mention not to use Identity framework for web APIs ? As far as I remember, there was no restriction to that... as we can build separate Identity provider for APIs use case ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg., I've read this right in the first section:

"ASP.NET Core Identity adds user interface (UI) login functionality to ASP.NET Core web apps. To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the following:

- Azure Active Directory
- Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
- IdentityServer4"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

So I'm not sure if the doc meant that it is not suitable for API-like projects

Comment: ohhh... I got it... basically `IS4` or `OpenIdDict` or some other third party Identity services handle the complexity part(OIDC, Oauth compliant, third party Identity provider). And they usually using with `Asp.Net Core Identity` for storing user, role and other system authentication related mechanism. So not using it alone with APIs, combining them. The good old days as `IS4` open source, `IS4` with MSIdentity was common couple. Nowadays, may be `OpenIdDict` would stand as an candidate.